# Show $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2x^{\frac{1}{4}}-x^3}dx <\infty$

Tags: integration, limits, improper-integrals

Show $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2x^{\frac{1}{4}}-x^3}dx <\infty$$

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2x^{\frac{1}{4}}-x^3}dx 
=\lim_{c\rightarrow0}\int_c^1 \frac{1}{2x^{\frac{1}{4}}-x^3}dx$$
exists by integrating and letting c tend to 0.

However I do not know how to compute this integral. Is there another way to show the integral is finite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{x^\frac{1}{4}}\frac{1}{2-x^{\frac{11}{4}}}\leq \frac{1}{x^\frac{1}{4}}\,,\forall x\in(0,1)$$

And  $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{4}}}\,dx<\infty$.

Often when you are asked to show something is finite , you will be required to compare it to other functions and see if the integral is finite or not.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: the expression under the integral near $0$ behaves like $1/(2x^{1/4})$.